# Linking models of spreading of infection to type of network describing the relationships of animals of a habitat

Tags: theoretical-biology, infectious-diseases, habitat

I am studying  networks describing the relationships between  animals in a habitat.There are many types of networks studied which are useful and we can approximate a real network to one of the studied networks.Now suppose a disease starts spreading in that habitat.There are state models of the spreading of the disease such as the SI ,SIS and SIR model.Inside these models there are different parameters which define the rate of infection , recovery or immunity.My question is : do these parameters depend on the type of the network which describes the relationship between the population?